# Zooming / font sizes / text scaling has a very limited range?

Tags: fonts, scaling, zooming

I would like to increase my font size, so I used the `C-x C-=` keybinding, followed by `=` to further increase the size. However, it stops zooming far too soon, and I realized that I can only cycle through 8 levels of zoom. I can zoom in twice past default and zoom out 5 times past default. Is there a way to increase the zoom range?

Additionally, when I continue trying to zoom (by pressing `=`) after reaching the max zoom level, I am unable to zoom out (by pressing `-`) until I press `-` the same number of times that I pressed `=`. For example, if at my max zoom level, I push `=` three times, I must push `-` three times with no results before I can push `-` again to zoom out. It seems as if the zoom levels are being recorded, but not rendered.

Here is the command that I am using via `C-h k C-x C-=`

```
C-x C-= runs the command text-scale-adjust, which is an interactive
autoloaded compiled Lisp function in `face-remap.el'.

It is bound to C-x C-0, C-x C-=, C-x C--, C-x C-+.

(text-scale-adjust INC)

Adjust the height of the default face by INC.

INC may be passed as a numeric prefix argument.

The actual adjustment made depends on the final component of the
key-binding used to invoke the command, with all modifiers removed:

   +, =   Increase the default face height by one step
   -      Decrease the default face height by one step
   0      Reset the default face height to the global default
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is related to a recent OS change (from Ubuntu to Arch), which included an Emacs upgrade from 24.3 to 24.4. I think my `.emacs.desktop` files were not compatible with this update, and this zoom bug was one effect. My desktop files are used to save my open buffers for each emacs session.

Thanks to @Drew's answer, I found the cause of this issue when commenting out the following line in my config:

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

When I comment it out, zooming worked fine. By deleting my old desktop files and creating new ones, I was able to uncomment the `desktop-save-mode` command again.

Answer (score 2):

Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? I doubt it. If so, and if your Emacs version is recent, report the problem: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

If not, then recursively bisect your init file to determine the culprit. You can use command `comment-region` to comment out a region of text (and with `C-u` it uncomments a region).

(With `emacs -Q`, I see virtually no limit on zooming size.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I should have remembered that myself :-) I updated my question, which was related to my `desktop-save-mode 1)` command.